# prevent second element of container to extend its width

Tags: html, css, sass

How to achieve that that only `<H1>` be able to extend the width of text-container, `<p>` not be able.

```
<style>
  .header-block {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  }

  .text-container {
    min-width: 40%;
    max-width: fit-content; 
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    min-width: 40%; 
    max-width: fit-content; 
    
  }

  h1 {
       width: max-content; 
      font-size: 50px;
      text-align: left;
      color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  p {
      font-size: 29px;
      text-align: justify;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      margin: 0;
  }
</style>

<div class="header-block">
  <div class="text-container">
    <h1>dsr waa  sd</h1>
    <p>adas ds dgdf as vrwsa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I write a longer title, yes i want the `.text-container` to extend beyond 40%, which works fine, but when I write long text of paragraph it also is extending the width of `.text-container` which I don't want to happen.

I tried all different styles and displays.